# Chat search returning no results

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, search

Searching for anything on [chat.Meta](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=test), [chat.SE](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=test), or [chat.SO](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=test&user=&room=) is currently coming up with zero results (including words that I *know* have hits because I've searched for them before, such as the name of [my D&D character in the D&D room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=kith&room=118089)). This happens if you search in a specific room, or just a general search.

[image: A chat.SE search for "kith" in the room PSE D&D Chatroom, with 0 messages found]

Chat rev 2021.1.28.906.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We're in the process of rebuilding one of the search clusters to a more recent build of Elastic and there was a blip where chat didn't connect to the failover site. I kicked it, it's now complying. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: I was hoping that repair of this bug would fix the [search bar in the chatroom itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8fw7.png), but that's not the case; it simply opens a blank *about* page. (Firefox Android). Not only should it have opened the search page but there was an item for it to find.